# Problem in loading javascript in footer

Tags: plugins, jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, footer

I have written a small plugin where i have loaded following scripts

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', plugins_url('/js/jquery.min.js', __FILE__),'','1.7',true);
wp_enqueue_script('new-cycle', plugins_url('/js/cycle.js', __FILE__),array( 'jquery' ),'1.0',true);
wp_enqueue_script('new-jcarousellite', plugins_url('/js/jcarousellite.js', __FILE__),array( 'jquery' ),'1.0',true);
wp_enqueue_script('new-fancybox', plugins_url('/js/fancybox.js', __FILE__),array( 'jquery' ),'1.0',true);
```

and i also have a javascript code to call cycle and fancybox functions ( with parameters/options loaded from options and post_meta tables )

```
function front_js(){ ?>   
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".video-popup").fancybox();
      $(".video_msgs").cycle({speed:'<?php echo get_option("cycle_speed");?>'});
    });
    </script>
<?php }
```

this code is added to footer by using `add_action('wp_footer', 'front_js');`

Now my javascript code is loaded before all the scripts required like

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".video-popup").fancybox();
  $(".video_msgs").cycle();
});
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/js/functions.js?ver=20141212'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/js/cycle.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/js/jcarousellite.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/js/fancybox.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/js/counter.js?ver=1.0'></script>
```

and giving error `$('...').fancybox()` not a function

I think its because the code is loaded before fancybox.js file where this function is written. I tried to print_scripts functions but its recommended to not to use this and `wp_enqueue_script` only works with files not with custom javascript code.

Is there any method to load my custom code after required files loaded or any other way to resolve this type of issue.

It works if I load all the files in header but then it increases page load time that is also not a good approach.

Comment: Hint: Add your script in its own js file and enqueue it as normal. Don't add scripts directly to `wp_footer`. Shortcut and not recommended method, use the `$priority` parameter of `add_action()` to hook your function later to `wp_footer`

Comment: it is working if i load my script through a js file but the functions here needs to be loaded with parameters that are fetched from options table. Let me edit my question and mention it as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the code to the footer using `add_action('wp_footer', 'front_js', 99);` where 99 specifies the order in which the functions are executed. Now it should be executed after your scripts are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the code in function and hooking it to `wp_footer`.

You can have another JS file stored in your plugin folder and enqueued it like other scripts you enqueued.

OR

```
<?php
function front_js() {
  if ( wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'done' ) ) {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".video-popup").fancybox();
      $(".video_msgs").cycle();
    });

</script>
<?php
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'front_js' );
?>
```